# Best way to connect to an existing user context through SSH

Tags: ssh, osx, remote, ssh-agent, remote-management

What we would like to do:

We have short living virtual machines for running scripts. The virtual machines are used through SSH to perform "builds" (sequence of scripts) and discarded once all the scripts finish. Every script runs through a new SSH connection/session.

This works really well for almost all of the scenarios we have, except two major use cases:

1. when the script have to control the iOS Simulator installed on the virtual machine (this is the primary use case we want to solve at the moment) - technical note: the iOS Simulator can only be properly controlled from a GUI context, right now we use a special Go based mini server (https://github.com/bitrise-io/xcodebuild-unittest-miniserver) which is started as a Launch Agent when the user signs in and so it has the user's GUI context
2. to maintain access to OS X keychain (through SSH the OS X keychains can be opened and managed but the keychain locks once the SSH session is closed)

Both of these issues could be solved if we could somehow start an agent inside the virtual machine and later we could connect to that specific daemon/agent, send the commands we want to run to the daemon/agent, and have the daemon/agent perform it. A requirement is to have a stream of the output of the actual scripts/commands which run inside the virtual machine.

**What we do right now** is to perform the scripts/commands through a simple SSH command like `ssh ssh-params 'bash -l -c "echo \"hello world\""'`. Of course this is a seriously simplified example but it's close to what we have right now, and with this we can get the *output* of the command as a stream to fulfill the logging requirement and additionally we can get the command's *exit code*.

So **what we would like to do** is something similar in terms that the command is specified "from outside" of the virtual machine but executed inside the virtual machine and the *output* of the command is available for the "outside" (caller) process as a stream, not just after the script finishes, as well as the command's *exit code* can be retrieved easily by the "outside" process.

In terms of tools we're quite open (we don't have to depend on SSH, that's just how it works at the moment) but the tool should be available for OS X and if possible for Linux (although in this case OS X is the priority, as both of the problematic use cases are related to OS X).

**TL;DR;** we would like a tool which can be used similarly to the above mentioned SSH command but it can connect to an agent/daemon which is already running at the remote (virtual machine) end, and the **output** generated by the specified "remote command" should be available for the caller process as a stream, *not just at the end of the command*. In addition to collecting the remote command's outputs we also have to be able to get it's **exit code**.

**Final words**: we ultimately decided to create our own solution because we couldn't figure out an easier way. You can find it on GitHub: https://github.com/bitrise-io/cmd-bridge - it supports all the required things I described and additionally it has command environment variable handling support (to define environment variables just for that remote command).

Comment: You're probably looking for something like `tmux` or `screen` if you're wanting to connect to an already-running console session.

Comment: @Bratchley We tried but could not figure out a way to collect the logs in a similar way we do with SSH. Could you show an example call which works similarly in terms of log output?

Comment: What were the problems you were running into?

Comment: Mainly: to run the command and get it's output right in the caller process, and to collect the command's exit code as well. Additionally the remote should not terminate the screen/window in case a script fails because the scripts are expected to return with non zero exit code.

Comment: Neither of these should be true of `tmux`. As long as you're not telling `tmux` to run the script itself, it should survive the end of the script's execution. You might try feeding your script to `bash` using the `--rcfile` option. You may have to alter the script so that it sources the user's `~/.bashrc` as the first thing if need be.

Comment: Also, probably the best thing to do if you're just going to wipe the VM anyways is to save the output to a file then anyone on the system can `cat` or `tail` the file to get its contents.

Comment: But that still required a second process, one for running the command and one for collecting it's output, right?

Comment: Why is that a huge deal?

Comment: Can be done if there's no better way but the point of the system is to run a sequence of scripts inside VMs and collect the logs and exit code of the individual scripts so it can be inspected on a webserver. Having a single process which can control the flow from the host makes it much easier to manage the whole process, for example to properly enforce the termination of the script in case it exceeds the timeout interval.

Comment: Not sure on OS X but on GNU/Linux you can do a `fuser -k` which will kill any programs that have the file open. Even if OS X doesn't have that you can still use `lsof` to locate the program writing to the file and get the PID to kill from there.

Comment: Ultimately, you're going to know more about how your setup actually works. My main point is that programs like `tmux` and `screen` are the means by which you re-join console session already in progress so if that's what you're wanting to do, you'll either have to handle signals in your script to do what you're wanting or use one of those two programs.

Comment: @Bratchley would you be open for a chat, as this discussion starts to be quite long? General note: what we would like to do is (if possible) to have a similar tool and flow we have with `ssh ssh-params 'bash -l -c "echo \"hello world\""'` - so that the caller can collect the logs/output of the command as well as it's exit code.

Answer (score 3):

Could you just run your commands in a screen or tmux session in the VM?  That would allow multiple steps to connect/send commands to the same session

Comment: We tried but could not figure out a way to collect the logs in a similar way we do with SSH. Could you show an example call which works similarly in terms of log output?

Comment: how about tee-ing the output of the commands to a file so that you can see on the screen and later collect from the session?

Comment: @lhasadad We would preferably collect the logs through the caller process and also collect the command's exit code there because both have to be transferred to a server. Do you know an example we could use?

Comment: When you're talking about collecting logs, do you mean getting the output of stdout?  If so I think lhasadad was probably on the right track.  If you have the commands teeing their output, you could have another ssh session that is watching that file in "real time."  If it's writing to a real log file you could have an ssh session tail-ing that file the whole time.  If those won't work I'll need a bit more info about why they aren't meeting the need in order to help find a better answer

Comment: I'll also point at STAF (staf.sourceforge.net) as an option for managed remote command execution.  I have used it for things like what your trying to do.  just a thought.

Comment: @EricRenouf sorry, I was referring to collecting the outputs (stdout) of the command. I also added an edit to the end of the question that we need to get the exit code of the command as well, in addition to the outputs.